# sort list in python by descending IP address and string order

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of strings like the below:

```
ip route vrf t141 0.0.0.0/0 10.76.102.101 name edge
ip route vrf t141 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101
ip route vrf t141 172.16.0.0/12 10.76.101.101
ip route vrf t141 192.168.0.0/16 10.76.101.101
ip route vrf t141 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101
ip route vrf t20 0.0.0.0/0 10.76.102.27
ip route vrf t20 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.27
ip route vrf t20 172.16.0.0/12 10.76.101.27
ip route vrf t20 192.168.0.0/16 10.76.101.27
ip route vrf t20 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.27
```

I need to sort the list by descending vrf name (t141, t20) as well as from descending IP address. `sort` and `sorted` are working ok for sorting the string based on vrf name but is not working ok for the IP addresses: the line `ip route vrf t141 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101` should be after `ip route vrf t141 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101` as well as `ip route vrf t20 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.27` should be after `ip route vrf t20 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.27` and not at the bottom.

Here the diff for better reading

```
 ip route vrf t10 0.0.0.0/0 10.76.102.25
 ip route vrf t10 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.25
+ip route vrf t10 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.25
 ip route vrf t10 172.16.0.0/12 10.76.101.25
 ip route vrf t10 192.168.0.0/16 10.76.101.25
-ip route vrf t10 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.25
 ip route vrf t141 0.0.0.0/0 10.76.102.101 name edge
 ip route vrf t141 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101
+ip route vrf t141 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101
 ip route vrf t141 172.16.0.0/12 10.76.101.101
 ip route vrf t141 192.168.0.0/16 10.76.101.101
-ip route vrf t141 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated

Comment: Should `t20` sort before or after `t141`?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Do you want to sort "alphabetically" ("t141" < "t20" and "172" < "29") or do you want to use the numbers in the strings (meaning t141 > t20 and 172 > 29) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to accomplish this result within the sorted method.

```
import re

ls = ['ip route vrf t141 0.0.0.0/0 10.76.102.101 name edge',
'ip route vrf t141 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101',
'ip route vrf t141 172.16.0.0/12 10.76.101.101',
'ip route vrf t141 192.168.0.0/16 10.76.101.101',
'ip route vrf t141 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101',
'ip route vrf t20 0.0.0.0/0 10.76.102.27',
'ip route vrf t20 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.27',
'ip route vrf t20 172.16.0.0/12 10.76.101.27',
'ip route vrf t20 192.168.0.0/16 10.76.101.27',
'ip route vrf t20 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.27']


print(*sorted(ls, key=lambda x: (int(re.search(r"(?:vrf t)(\w*)", x).group(1)), " ".join([i for i in x.split(" ") if not re.sub("[0-9.\/]", "", i)]))), sep="\n")
```

Output

```
ip route vrf t20 0.0.0.0/0 10.76.102.27
ip route vrf t20 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.27
ip route vrf t20 172.16.0.0/12 10.76.101.27
ip route vrf t20 192.168.0.0/16 10.76.101.27
ip route vrf t20 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.27
ip route vrf t141 0.0.0.0/0 10.76.102.101 name edge
ip route vrf t141 10.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101
ip route vrf t141 172.16.0.0/12 10.76.101.101
ip route vrf t141 192.168.0.0/16 10.76.101.101
ip route vrf t141 29.0.0.0/8 10.76.101.101
```